# How to send a messages.properties key to an exception being thrown in a controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I am trying to implement custom messages with a different language in my application built with Spring Boot 2. So far I have implemented it for entities' fields using keys set in `messages_br.properties`. Now, I'm trying the same with exception messages thrown in controllers, but I don't understand how to do it. Examples show too much of things I believe is not what I need.

To configure the file, this is in my `Application.java`:

```java
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bundleMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    bundleMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages_br");
    bundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    return bundleMessageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());

    return bean;
}
```

In the annotations above each field, I can specify something like this:

```java
@NotEmpty(message = "{beneficiary.name.notEmpty}")
private String name;
```

But the same format in a thrown exception prints that only:

```java
throw new InsufficientBalanceException("${user.balance.insufficientBalance}");
```

I'm almost sure that when learning how to implement exceptions I saw a similar example but now I cannot find it anymore nor I remember how it is done.

Comment: You may define a property for error and use `@Value("${user.balance.insufficientBalance}")` then use this property in exception.

Comment: Isn't there a way I can directly read the keys from the file without having to create another property?

Comment: You may use `Environment` to directly read value from file. Please check my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a property for error message with `@Value`,

```
@Value("${user.balance.insufficientBalance}")
private String insufficientBalance;
```

And then use it in Exception,

```
throw new InsufficientBalanceException(insufficientBalance);
```

If you don't want to create extra property, you can use `Environment`

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:messages_br.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    public void getErrorMessage() {
        env.getProperty("insufficientBalance");
    }
    //then use getErrorMessage
    throw new InsufficientBalanceException(getErrorMessage);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm experiencing an error message saying `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: messages_br.properties (No such file or directory)` when using `@PropertySource`.

Comment: When we use `file` in `@PropertySource`, file has to e there at specified location. You can use  `classpath` if if properties file is present in classpath.i.e `@PropertySource("classpath:messages_br.properties")` Let me know if it solves your issue.